# How do I get JOSM to scale on HiDPi screen?

Tags: 22.04

I ran into this issue on my 4K screen where the flatpack version of JOSM would scale and the version I downloaded from their recommended repository wouldn't scale.

I was able to change the scaling of JOSM if I ran `GPK_SCALING=2 josm` from the command line. But I wanted to be able to not have to start my application from the command line. On Ubuntu 22.04 was able to resolve my issue by adding the following to `/etc/default/josm`:

`JAVA_OPTS="-Dsun.java2d.uiScale=2"`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to change the scaling of JOSM if I ran GPK_SCALING=2 josm from the command line, but I wanted to be able to not have to start my application from the command line. In Ubuntu 22.04 I was able to resolve my issue by adding the following to `/etc/default/josm` :

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Dsun.java2d.uiScale=2"
```